# C# - Opening text file via another form (read description)

Tags: c#, forms, text, drag-and-drop

I made a simple 'notepad' program that read and writes text files. Another cool thing is that whenever I double click on saved file it will open my program and write the content on my RichTextBox (called 'area'). This is what made that happen:

In **Program.cs** i added 'args' in columns

```
Application.Run(new Form1(args));
```

Next in my **Form1.cs** I have this code

```
public Form1(string[] file)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        area.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(area_DragDrop);
        area.AllowDrop = true;
        if (file.Length != 0)
            pathstart = file[0];

    }

string pathstart = null;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pathstart != null)
        {
            area.LoadFile(pathstart, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
        }
    }
```

Now, that's all working fine.

**NOW**

I added a new form (that opens when program starts) that is just ***user authentication***

And instead of this

```
Application.Run(new Form1(args));
```

**I now have this**

```
Application.Run(new identy(args));
```

The issue here is that now, when I double click on my saved file, it won't open the content in RichTextBox ('area') after authentication.

Any ideas how can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't initialise the identity form, go back to initialising Form1:

```
Application.Run(new Form1(args));
```

Then, from within the Form1 constructor, create and display the identity form, like this:

```
public Form1(string[] file)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    area.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(area_DragDrop);
    area.AllowDrop = true;

    identity ident = new identity();
    ident.ShowDialog();

    if (ident.Authenticated)
    {
         if (file.Length != 0)
            pathstart = file[0];
    }
}
```

Create a property in the ident class/form called Authenticated and set the value accordingly after you check the credentials:

```
public bool AuthenticatedOk { get; set; }

public identity()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.AuthenticatedOk = false;
}

private void checkDetails(string username, string password)
{
    if (username=="bob" && password=="password")
    {
        this.AuthenticatedOk = true;
    }
}
```